# SQL displaying duplicate values in tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to get a query that will display details of persons that have the same banking details, that have been captured in error.

I need to then display both the correct details as well as the incorrect details of these persons.  For instance:

```
1stName   1stAccNo   1stItemSold    2ndName   2ndAccNo  2ndItemSold
Albert    2231432     Item1         John      2231432   Item3
Robert    6321009     Item11        Peter     6321009   Item3
```

Name and AccNo are on one table, and ItemSold are on a different table.

I have the following query:

```
select p1.Name As 1stName, p1.AccNo AS 1stAccNo, I.ItemSold AS 1stItemSold, p2.Name AS 2ndName, p2.AccNo AS 2ndAccNo, I.ItemSold As 2ndItemSold
FROM Persons p1 JOIN Persons p2 ON p1.AccNo = p2.AccNo 
INNER JOIN Items I on p.ItemID = I.ItemID
```

The problem is that 2nd ItemSold is not correct, because it is the same as the 1stItemSold.  What do I do to change my query so that I may achieve the correct results?

Comment: What kind of SQL? Do you only ever sell 2 items to people?

Comment: SQL Server 2008.  No, the problem is that sometimes, the are more than 2 people with the same account number.  One instance I found was 8 people with the same account number.

Comment: @user1668123 can you provide some sample data for both tables? Or even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model

Answer (score 1):

You should join Items as a second table. Also If you need the different people you have to include `where p1.id<>p2.id` where ID is a primary key in the PERSONS table

```
select 
p1.Name As 1stName, p1.AccNo AS 1stAccNo, I1.ItemSold AS 1stItemSold, 
p2.Name AS 2ndName, p2.AccNo AS 2ndAccNo, I2.ItemSold As 2ndItemSold
FROM Persons p1 JOIN Persons p2 ON p1.AccNo = p2.AccNo 
INNER JOIN Items I1 on p1.ItemID = I1.ItemID
INNER JOIN Items I2 on p2.ItemID = I2.ItemID
where p1.id<>p2.id
```

PS: based on comment. Return the last ItemSold to avoid duplicates:

```
select 
p1.Name As 1stName, p1.AccNo AS 1stAccNo, I1.ItemSold AS 1stItemSold, 
p2.Name AS 2ndName, p2.AccNo AS 2ndAccNo, I2.ItemSold As 2ndItemSold
FROM Persons p1 JOIN Persons p2 ON p1.AccNo = p2.AccNo 
left JOIN 
   (select ItemID,ItemSold, 
           row_number() over (PARTITION BY ItemID order by DATE_SOLD DESC) as rn 
    from Items) I1 
         on (p1.ItemID = I1.ItemID) and (rn=1)
left JOIN 
   (select ItemID,ItemSold, 
           row_number() over (PARTITION BY ItemID order by DATE_SOLD DESC) as rn 
    from Items) I2 
         on (p2.ItemID = I2.ItemID) and (rn=1)

where p1.id<>p2.id
```

Comment: I tried that, but I get unnecessary duplicate results from that query.

Comment: It is because you have more than one item for one person. So you should decide what to do in this case.

Comment: If there is more than one item for one person, then I need to return the first item that was purchased, based on purchase date.

Comment: Do you have an email address that I could use to send the actual query to? Its a lot more complex than the example I gave here.

Answer (score 1):

I might be misinterpreting your requirements but it sounds like you can use the [`UNPIVOT/PIVOT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function to get the results you need.

If you know the number of columns to transform, then you can hard-code a static version of this.

```
select *
from
(
  select AccNo,
    val,
    col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) Col_Name
  from
  (
    select p1.accno,
      p1.name,
      p1.itemid,
      i1.id,
      i1.i_name,
      row_number() over(partition by accno order by name) rn
    from persons p1
    left join items i1
      on p1.itemid = i1.id
  ) x
  unpivot
  (
    val
    for col in (name, i_name)
  ) u
) x1
pivot
(
  max(val)
  for col_name in ([name1], [i_name1], [name2], [i_name2])
) p
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77cfe/9)

But it sounds like you will have an unknown number of items to transform to columns, so you can use dynamic SQL and create a dynamic version of this:

```
DECLARE @colsUnPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @colsPivot AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @colsUnPivot = stuff((select ','+C.name
         from sys.columns as C
         where (C.object_id = object_id('persons') 
                  or C.object_id = object_id('items'))
            and C.name like '%name%'
         for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')

select @colsPivot = STUFF((SELECT  ',' 
                      + quotename(c.name 
                         + cast(p.rn as varchar(10)))
                    from
                    (
                      select row_number() over(partition by accno order by name) rn
                      from persons
                    ) p
                     cross apply 
                      sys.columns as C
                   where (C.object_id = object_id('persons') 
                            or C.object_id = object_id('items'))
                      and C.name like '%name%'
                   group by c.name, p.rn
                   order by p.rn, c.name desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query 
  = 'select *
      from
      (
          select AccNo,
            val,
            col + cast(rn as varchar(10)) Col_Name
        from 
        (
          select p1.accno,
            p1.name,
            p1.itemid,
            i1.id,
            i1.i_name,
            row_number() over(partition by accno order by name) rn
          from persons p1
          left join items i1
            on p1.itemid = i1.id
        ) x
        unpivot
        (
          val
          for col in ('+ @colsunpivot +')
        ) u
      ) x1
      pivot
      (
        max(val)
        for col_name in ('+ @colsPivot + ')
      )p'

exec(@query)
```

## see [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/77cfe/28)

Comment: I tried replicating what you did in the query above, but I am very lost when it comes to pivot/unpivot.  Is there any easier way to do this?

Comment: @user1668123 I cannot see of another way to do this if you have an unknown number of columns.  If you have a specific question about how the pivot/unpivot works, please ask and I will clarify it.

Comment: @user1668123 I do not, however you can always use [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) to create your data model.